# Dynamic DataTemplate for GridViewDataColumn

Tags: wpf

I have two columns at the moment. Column one is a combo box Type which can be Phone or Email. Column two is value. I currently have two datatemplates, one for the phone type which comes with a mask. If it's email, it's a regular textbox with no mask. May I ask how do I make it dynamic?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PhoneMaskTemplate">
     <Telerik:RadMaskedTextBox BorderBrush="Transparent"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Mask="(###) ###-#### x####" 
                               MaskedText="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" >
      </Telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NoMaskTemplate">
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
     </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<Telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Value" Width="*" 
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `DataTemplateSelector`, which you can set in `Telerilk:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplateSelector` property.

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate PhoneTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
       if(IsPhone(item))
           return PhoneTemplate;
       else if(IsEmail(item))
           return EmailTemplate;
       else
           return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Then you have:

```
<local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" 
                              PhoneTemplate="{StaticResource PhoneMaskTemplate}" 
                              EmailTemplate="{StaticResource NoMaskTemplate}" />
```

Your column:

```
<Telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Value" Width="*" 
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"
                            CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" />
```

You should only properly implement `IsPhone` and `IsEmail` methods.

Comment: Hi Kedrzu, Couple issues I got with the code. GetValue and SetValue isn't recognized along with BaseDataTemplateSelector. I Think BaseDataTemplateSelector should be DataTemplateSelector. And another question before I continue to try this, will this update when properties are also changed? For example if I change between Phone and Email, will the templates update?

Comment: You are right, should be `DataTemplateSelector`. Templates are static, and will not update. Controls created basing on these templates will update properly.

Comment: You should also check what type the `item` is in `SelectTemplate` method. Not sure, whether this is the provided value, or the whole item bound to grid view row.

Comment: Yeah I am checking the type, thanks. One more thing that wasn't addressed if you can. "GetValue" and "SetValue" isn't recognized.

Comment: Oh snap, `DataTemplateSelector` is not `DependencyObject`. Since then, you should use regular properties instead of dependency properties. Will edit this in a moment.

Comment: I like the approach, SO CLEAN. only thing I'm missing is having the UI update on changes